# CoreMotion apparently calls UI API from background thread

Tags: xcode, uikit, xcode10, core-motion

At some point in my app I am initializing a CMMotionManager. This happens on the main thread. After doing so, the Xcode 10 main thread checker indicates that

```
-[UIApplication applicationState]
```

is not being called from the main thread. Indeed it is coming from

```
Thread name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
```

Since this is Apple's private framework it appears to me that I just have to wait until this issue is fixed on Apple's side. Am I correct and/or is there any way to remedy this issue without switching off the main thread checker?

Answer (score 2):

Its currently a bug in the API, something is triggering in background thread.

i could stop it with

```
lazy var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
```

see also https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD/issues/98, but there is no solution right now.

Comment: The lazy call will only postpone the exception.